# PL/SQL procedure to inset data from one table to another table but need to insert those record which column 3 have null

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to create pl/sql procedure to insert data from one table to another table , but i need to  filter those record from one column which is not null in column.

Example :-

```
C1 | C2| C3|
------------
1  | 2 |   |
3  | 4 | 5 |
6  | 7 |   |
-------------
```

I want to filter column c3 second record and insert the remaining record to another table.

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: for your next question: "c3 second record" is unclear. it can be rownum=2, c3=5 or c3 is not null

Answer (score 1):

I assume there would be a need of procedure for some work and the question you asked is a prototype of actual problem. If not then what @Aleksej suggested is correct.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure copyTable is 
 cursor source_table is 
   select c1, c2, c3
   from table1
   where c3 is null;

  TYPE var_temp  IS TABLE OF source_table%rowtype ;

  v_var var_temp;

begin 

open source_table;

 fetch source_table bulk collect into v_var;

 close source_table;

  FORALL i IN v_var.first .. v_var.last 
     INSERT INTO table2
   VALUES v_var(i);

end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple insert-as-select query, with no need for PLSQL:

```
insert into table2(c1, c2, c3)
select c1, c2, c3
from table1
where c3 is null
```